# Multiple instance UIView only load xib file in the first instance

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview

I'm working on as slideshow with some `CustomUIView` showed in a `UIScrollView` and it works good. But i have a custom `UIView` to show the content of each news. My slide works goods , but the XIB file of my custom view is loaded only for the first one and other customview are empty.

Here is my code :

my ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:YES];

    int nbrNews = _sharedDataManager.rssfeeds.count;
    _sliderView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width*nbrNews, self.view.frame.size.height);

    self.pageControl.currentPage = 0;
    self.pageControl.numberOfPages = nbrNews;

    for (int i = 0; i< nbrNews; i++) {
         NewsView *newsView = [[NewsView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(i*self.view.frame.size.width, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];


        NSDictionary *news = [_sharedDataManager.rssfeeds objectAtIndex:i];
        newsView.titleLabel.text = [news objectForKey:@"title"];

        [_sliderView addSubview:newsView];

    }

}
```

CustomView.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface NewsView : UIView

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *titleLabel;


@end
```

CustomView.m

```
#import "NewsView.h"

@implementation NewsView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"OneNewsView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

here the result : 
EDITED : i change the color of the view in my custom view. and we can see that only the first one is realy loaded with xib file. and i dont know why !!!! can you help me?

[image]

[image]

Comment: For some reason your frame calculations and more specific `x` coordinates are always `0` that makes your `customView` be placed on top of each other.

Comment: thanks dude, i solve my problem by adding :
    self.frame = frame;
to my customView initWithFrame.

Answer (score 0):

i solve my problem by adding :

```
  self.frame = frame;
```

to my customView.m initWithFrame